# VBA Variant Overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running the below function that I found online

```
Function ConvertStringToNumber(str As Variant) As Long

    Dim retval As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    retval = ""

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Mid(str, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(str, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(str, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ConvertStringToNumber = retval '''''''''ERROR HERE

End Function
```

I'm receiving the error `Run-time error '6': Over Flow`, from what I've found online it has to do with my system resources

These are the inputs I've attempted:

> "3aaab   23as454s24h23423ad"
>
> **Result: Overflow**
>
> "3aaab   23as454s24hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhad"
>
> **Result: 32345424**
>
> "^*&asdasd^&sdasd*^&^6776**^*&^asdasd"
>
> **Result: 6776**
>
> "5asdasd 7 h4gregw56u 5 45j2dfg  dfgdj46   n5k42n2"
>
> **Result: Overflow**

Any idea why some of these are working fine? And some are not?

Comment: You're returning a `Long`. `retval` needs to fit a `Long`. It being declared `As Variant` is useless, whatever its value, it needs to fit a `Long`. You can't have an integer value greater than `2^31-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a number to a `Long` variable.  According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary) a `Long` can accept any number up to `2,147,483,647`.

So you will get an overflow if you try to assign the numbers `3,234,542,423,423` (i.e. the number after taking the non-numeric characters out of `"3aaab 23as454s24h23423ad"`) or `574,565,452,465,422` (i.e. the number after taking the non-numeric characters out of `"5asdasd 7 h4gregw56u 5 45j2dfg dfgdj46 n5k42n2"`) to it.

Comment: Agreed.  If you're not currently editing to add this :) , would you please mention the skip-alpha that produces the long numbers?  I think that is also an important part of the answer.